# How can I change the name of an Image in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

At the moment I'm using python on a Raspberry. My goal is that the picture, that the raspberry takes from a PiCamera should be save on the desktop with different names. 
Example : 
It take a photo and safe it as image1. The Next image should be safe as image2 (without using a loop that takes 5 photos in a row.

Here is my Code that I use at the moment :

```
import time                                                             
from picamera import PiCamera                                           


cam = PiCamera()                                                         
fname = (time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d_%H:%M:%S"))                            

cam.resolution = (1920, 1080)                                           
cam.framerate = 30                                                  

cam.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image' + str(fname) +'.jpg')
```

Comment: What's not working with this code? It will save a unique picture given the current time stamp? is that not enough? Except you should ditch the extra parenthesizes around `time.strftime()`

Comment: I don't want that the picture called like the current time but with numbers. Due to my goal, it should save pictures from 1 object from different sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `image1.jpg`, `image2.jpg`, `image3.jpg` and so on, are created exactly in this order you could get name of newest (i.e. having greatest number) following way:

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/pi/Desktop/image')
images = [i for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if i.lower().startswith('image')]
if images:
    newest = max(images,key=os.path.getmtime)
else:
    newest = 'image0.jpg'
```

If there is not image at all, I set `newest` to `image0.jpg` string (however I do not create such file). Then we need to extract number from that name, it can be done for example following way:

```
number = int(''.join([i for i in newest if i.isdigit()]))
```

Above line assumes that all `image` names are correct and follows pattern: `image_.jpg` where `_` is number. Finally we could create name for new image:

```
newimagen = 'image'+str(number+1)+'.jpg'
```

Now you could use it in your `capture` method argument:

```
'/home/pi/Desktop/'+newimagen
```